# A method to do mailing with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a specific request, I would know if it's possible to do mailing with Laravel.

In my case I would like to send SMS to different people stocked in my database, and with a single message use variables that refer to columns in the database.

Like this :[image]

Message:

```
Hello {nom_client}, please confirm you live at {adresse} {cp_commune}, {commune}.
```

Would give :

> Hello **Stack OVERFLOW**, please confirm you live at **stackoverflow.com 00000**, **Sovfw**.

I need to send a lot of message in one time (I'm using an API to send the messages).

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Mailing or SMS? They're not the same.

Comment: I translated a word to define this in french "publipostage" and the translate in english was mailing

Answer (score 1):

You can check the docs about notifications here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications

Or https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications if you are using the newest version of Laravel.

I think you will find what you are trying to do there.